# Symlink.exe always asking for permission when creating a new directory

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I use [link shell extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) for windows extensively, as it's a really neat tool. However every time I want to create a new folder on any partition of mine, `symlink.exe` asks for admin permissions. It got a little bit annoying, and it made it impossible for me to create shared folder with virtualbox, as for security reasons it won't work for symlinks. When checking with `dir /AL`, files within those folders are not symlinks of any kind.

The main question is: Why would this program trigger every time I create a folder?

Did anybody encountered such problem before (google stays silent)?

Also, can I check with any tool (from sysinternals for example), what triggers this action?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why you need admin to create a directory link? Or that your filesystem permissions are somehow screwed up?

Comment: I edited the question. When I'm not working with symlinks, it shouldn't trigger at all.